# Cloning Dual Boot iMac to a new iMac

Tags: windows-7, macos, imac

I have an iMac that dual boots to Windows 7 using Bootcamp. I just purchased a new iMac and I'd like to fully clone my old iMac to the new iMac. I've done this before using a firewire cord and starting as a target drive.

Would this same method work to transfer both operating systems in one go?

Answer (score 1):

Disk Utility does not work with cloning NTFS formatted partitions and is not able to restore them from disk images as well.

I would set up the Mac and transfer the data as you did in the past for OSX. Once you are done, you can use a utility like [Winclone](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25932/winclone) to migrate the Bootcamp partition to your new machine.

Hope you enjoy the new iMac!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I used migration assistant for the OSX side of things. It worked great. Winclone looks to be discontinued though